# how to generate an invoice

Tags: linux, pdf, client, invoice

I have started freelancing and a client has asked for an invoice.

Do you have a favorite tool for generating invoices? I am after something that I can use from Linux (either a desktop tool or web solution) and generates well formatted Pdf's.

thanks

Comment: Umm... OpenOffice (http://www.openoffice.org/)? This will likely be closed as "not programming related".

Comment: I'd personally go the OpenOffice route because there are so many Word/Excel templates for invoicing readily available.  Someone else might have a better solution closer to what you are after though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenOffice spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

Gnucash. It has that.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Books is the defacto standard in this space these days but if you only use linux you can try http://www.quickbooksonline.com

Answer (score 0):

You can give [NeoInvoice](http://www.neoinvoice.com) a try (it's in beta, but stable).